# OpenVPN client behind CGNAT, traffic only passing server to client

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, draytek

I have a Draytek Vigor 2927ax router with built-in OpenVPN server at my main site on a static IPv4.

I'm trying to establish a VPN tunnel from a remote site using the OpenVPN client built in to an Asus AX11000 router; Internet access is via a Starlink connection which uses CGNAT. The router sees a WAN address of `100.102.x.x` but whatismyip.com gives `145.224.x.x`.

Conceptually what I'm trying to achieve is:
192.168.5.x <=> Draytek-2927 <=> WAN ---VPN--- WAN <=> Asus-AX11000 <=> 192.168.50.x

The VPN tunnel comes up and I can ping the LAN on the client side from the LAN on the server side: `ping 192.168.50.10` receives replies.

But from the client side I can't ping the Draytek or anything on the LAN behind it: `ping 192.168.5.1` fails. However a traceroute does appear to reach the Draytek:

```
C:\Users\x>tracert 192.168.5.5
Tracing route to 192.168.5.5 over a maximum of 30 hops

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  GT-AX11000-6E50 [192.168.50.1]
2    46 ms    45 ms    41 ms  192.168.5.1
3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
...
```

This leads me to think that it's the Draytek that's blocking the traffic, perhaps because it appears to originate from a different IP address to the tunnel endpoint (due to the CGNAT).

I've tried temporarily disabling the firewall and defence features to unblock it but no matter what I try I can't reach the Draytek from the remote site.

Can anyone spot anything I've missed or suggest what to try next?

Comment: I don't think the CGNAT should have much relevance – the very purpose of a tunnel is that traffic coming inside the tunnel is not coupled to the IP address of the tunnel endpoint in any way; only the "outer" OpenVPN packets use the endpoint address. Depending on whether a packet capture shows the remote devices receiving your pings or not, it's most likely a regular firewall issue at some place (e.g. the remote device refusing to answer pings from outside the subnet).

Comment: Remote devices don't seem to be seeing any traffic from the tunnel. The reason I thought CGNAT may be relevant is that I have a couple of IPSEC tunnels to other remote sites on static IPs that work well.